# Merge Query With Delete From Target Condition

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, upsert, sql-merge

I am working on a task where my source is AWS RDS - SQL Server and my target is Azure SQL Server.
There's a table with 80M records in my source that needs to be **merged** with my target table.
This merging will happen every 15 mins and based on the `business key`, I need to -

1. Update the target table if the key is updated in the source table.
2. Insert a new key into the target table.
3. Mark `isDeleted` as `true` in the target if the key is no more present in the source.

**IMP Note** - The source row is hard-deleted and no history is maintained.

Since this merging happens every 15 mins and the source table is pretty big, I use `lastUpdated` column to select only limited records in the source query of my merge query.

With this, I am able to perfectly handle the "upsert" scenario, but on delete, it is deleting all the records from the target which is not desirable.

I have tried the below option -

Read the entire source table in a `temp_table` every 15 mins and then perform merge from `temp_table` to the target table. But this is very costly in terms of processing and time.

Is there any better way to handle this scenario? I am happy to share more information as needed.

Comment: Is it possible to update the target table schema? like add new column

Comment: yes, I can add a new column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the problem by adding new column called `SyncStamp`, the idea is, we update or insert the same value for SyncStamp, So the other rows that have not this value should be updated as IsDeleted.

I prefer to get the actual timestamp for SyncStamp but you can choose random numbers.

```sql
    --get timestamp 
    Declare @SyncStamp bigint = (SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(Second, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE()))

    MERGE TargetTable AS Target
    USING SourceTable   AS Source
    ON Source.BusinessKey = Target.BusinessKey
    
    -- For Inserts
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, SyncStamp) 
        VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, @SyncStamp)
    
    -- For Updates
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        Target.ProductName  = Source.ProductName,
        Target.SyncStamp        = @SyncStamp;
        

    --Update isDeleted
    UPDATE TargetTable
    SET IsDeleted= 1
    Where IsDeleted=0 and SyncStamp <> @SyncStamp
```

Comment: Hi @sa-es-ir , this will work only if we read the entire source data every time correct? But reading a table with 80M records every 15 mins is costly.

Comment: @SanketKelkar You can create index on SyncStamp with filter IsDeleted=0 and it will be fast, there is no way to do your case with Merge query.